# When will the .NET 4 Client Profile be pushed out over Windows Update?

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-update, .net-client-profile

When will the .NET 4 Client Profile be pushed out over Windows Update? Is there a published timeframe, or do we have any educated guesses?

Scott Hanselman [said](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TowardsASmallerNET4DetailsOnTheClientProfileAndDownloadingNET.aspx) "later this year."

Comment: .NET 4 is now available on Windows Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Hanselman also said:

> About 6-8 weeks after the .NET Framework 4 launches, the .NET 4 Client Profile will show up on Windows Update (WU) and Windows Server Update Service (WSUS) as it's considered part of the serviceable operating system.

.NET Framework 4 was launched 12 April, so i hope Client Profile will be available through Windows Update not later than 15 June.

Comment: Wow... don't know how I missed that >_<

Answer (score 3):

It is available on Windows Update now. It is optional on XP and recommended on Vista and Windows 7.
See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982670